# Scripting Language That Sends GUI Events To Any GUI App

Tags: scripts, automation

I would like to run scripts that will allow me to interact with the gui by sending windows events such as:

- button presses
- text insertion
- window closing, minimizing
- utilize an apps quick key combinations
- etc.

Is there something out there for Ubuntu that does this?

Comment: same question in my head, upvoted.

Comment: I hope we get this answer.  Fingers x

Comment: I was trying bashscript..

Comment: I guess some1 will point you to phyton, before your question goes closed.

Comment: Remember to choose right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the world of old programmers, *script* and *GUI* are two words that live in totally different worlds. That looks like a myth very well established for many reasons.

Any way, the world of web applications is throwing this tine line away, and more and more people are looking for this, and some of them point this as a new tendence.

Why not simple scripts, with simple gui's? First one to start this kind of project, BUMM...

Well, I did my shots at **Bashscript**, as I am a big beginner in programming. You can take a look at

1. **xdotool**
2. **glade**
3. **gtk**

   and the obvius **phyton** advanced scripting language, which I know nothing about it. (google about this itens, they will be very helpfull whatever language you choose it)

The **`dialog`** command in bash is very nice to do some simple Gui's, I guess this is the best beggining I can point you. xdotool is a interactive mouse/keyboard tool, glade is a full program to make Gui for many languages, and gtk is a lybrary/toolkit u can use with C++ or Pỳthon I guess... Good research wait for you.

Comment: I guess is gTK+-2.0

Comment: +1 for xdotool that actually does the UI-automation.

Answer (score 0):

zenity might be useful for this task. look at the manual pages. below is a simpe bash script example. hope it helps someone.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# filename: cylvolcal.sh
#
# simple example of using zenity to interact with a graphical user from a bash script
# ubuntu version 14.04
#
# calculate the volume of a cylinder with diameter and length entered by the user
# and have the answer displayed to the user in a graphical info box.
# bash doesn't handle decimals well so pi is set to 3
#
dia1=`zenity --entry --title="enter diameter" --text="in metres"`
len1=`zenity --entry --title="enter length" --text="in metres"`
rad1=$((dia1/2))
pi1=3
rad2=$((rad1*rad1))
vol1=$((pi1*rad2*len1))
zenity --info --title="cylinder volume" --text="the volume of your cylinder is `echo $vol1`"
exit 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about what this code does. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity seems related.